# Как отобразить Recycler View в bottom sheet?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне нужно создать bottom sheet с двумя view : горизонтальный rececler view и под ним liner layout. Как это сделать, если bottom sheet я реализую через BottomSheetDialogFragment. Попытался объявить там recyclerview, как в обычных фрагментах, но он при тесте на устройстве не отображается. Как это исправить?
Вот разметка bottom sheet

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/chat_sheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_chat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

<include layout="@layout/line_divider" />

<LinearLayout . . . >

</LinearLayout>
```

Вот код java файла BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
public class ChatBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

private ArrayList<SheetObject> cardList;
private RecyclerSheetAdapter mAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sheet_chat, container, false);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_chat);
    cardList = new ArrayList<>();
    mAdapter = new RecyclerSheetAdapter(this, cardList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    //recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: А вы его и не наполняете данными... А его высота wrap_content, соответственно он пустой

Comment: @RomanK. я его наполнил данными prepareMovieData();  Если бы он был просто пустой, то должен оставаться хотя бы белый фон от него, а тут он просто не отображается, будто невидимым становится